# User defined forms, Store data of different types, 1 table vs multiple

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I am looking into building a way for administrative users to dynamically create forms with custom fields they define. There will be a few different data types as follows:

`varchar(200)`, `varchar(max)`, `Date`, `int`, etc...

I plan on having a table named `formCollectedData` to hold the general form submission information, then have another table that has a row for each field entered in by the user filling out the form.

In regards to database structure, I can either have one table to store all the entered in fields as follows:

[image]

Where only one of these null-able fields would actually store data at a time, based on the form element that collected it.

Or for each data type have a separate table

[image]

**I am leaning toward just having one table that has null-able fields for each of the data types, mainly since it simplifies joins and such, but I would like to get other opinions on if breaking them up into separate tables has any benefit in the long run. Any thoughts?**

Likely a few hundred forms would be submitted daily for now, and for each form you would generally have 10 fields.

I'm in the C# world and planning on using Linq.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an opinion, so here is mine.

The benefit from creating multiple tables here is that you avoid null values. As described in this article, http://www.sql-server-citation.com/2009/12/common-mistakes-in-sql-server-part-4.html , null values takes disk space. It is also not really sexy to have a table with plenty of null ( from a database design point of view ).

To be honnest, it could be a real pain to treat with so many tables, so if you have to query manually the table quite often (especially with inserts and updates), I'll go for one table only. And for about 40K rows a year, this is not such a big deal.

This is your call now, pick between the beautiful or the handy way :-)